# Post ajax data to php and then get the data not work

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i've got some problem

my html:
http://jsfiddle.net/dHdnb/

my jquery:

```
$(".header_nav li a").click(function(){
  var href = this.href;
  $.ajax({
  url: 'dynamic.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: { target: href },
  success: setTimeout(function(){
           $.ajax({
           url: 'dynamic.php',
           dataType: 'html',
           data: { target: href},               
           success: function(data) {
                    $(".container").html(data)
                    }           
           })
           }, 1000)

})
```

here is my php code:

```
<?php
  $target = $_POST["target"];
  echo $target;

  function home(){
  echo $target;
  // some command
  }
  switch($target) {
  case "home": home();
  break;
  // and so on
  default;
  }

  $target = isset($_POST['target']) ? $_POST['target'] : 'default_target_value';
  echo $target;

  echo "Test ajax";
?>
```

lets me explain this, if the user click the button on those list
then, it will post the target variable into the server
then, the server will process the request and launch a function
finally, when the ajax process success, it will load the data from the server into the container div

my question is, why it's gave me an error like this?
**"Notice: Undefined index: target in xxx.php on line 7"**
i know there must be something wrong with my data on my ajax,
but i don't know where's my mistakes
please help me :)

when i'm debug it with charles, the ajax send the data with text string like this
my **POST** request raw:

> POST /xxx/dynamic.php HTTP/1.1
>   Host  xxx
>   Content-Length    67
>   Accept    */*
>   Origin    http ://xxx
>   X-Requested-With  XMLHttpRequest
>   User-Agent    xx
>   Content-Type  application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
>   Referer   http:/xxx.php
>   Accept-Encoding   gzip,deflate,sdch
>   Accept-Language   en-US,en;q=0.8
>
> target=http%3A%2F%2Fxx%2Fxx%2Fhome.php%23product

my **POST** response raw:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Date: Tue, 10 Sep 2013 09:35:19 GMT
>   Server: Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.16
>   X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.16
>   Content-Length: 57
>   Content-Type: text/html
>
> http ://xxx.php#productTest ajax

my **GET** request raw:

> GET xxx.php HTTP/1.1
>   Host: xxx
>   Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01
>   X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
>   User-Agent: xx
>   Referer: http ://xxx.php
>   Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
>   Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

my **GET** response raw:

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Date: Tue, 10 Sep 2013 09:45:43 GMT
>   Server: Apache/2.4.4 (Win32) OpenSSL/0.9.8y PHP/5.4.16
>   X-Powered-By: PHP/5.4.16
>   Content-Length: 152
>   Content-Type: text/html
>
> **Notice**:  Undefined index: target in **dynamic.php** on line **2**
>   Test ajax

Comment: no that's not good, i want the my address bar just like this "www.bla.com/home.php#home"

Comment: FIrst, check if it is a POST request; normally done by `if( isset($_POST['target']) ){...`

Comment: it's give me a blank container :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is the valid code!

```
var href = this.href;
        $.ajax({
        url: 'dynamic.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { target: href },
        success: function (data) {
                    setTimeout(function (){
                    $(".container").html(data)
                    }, 1000)
                }
        });
```

you don't need to do the **get ajax** command, you just need to directly output the data in the **success:** above! :)

Comment: sorry guys i can't vote you all up, i don't have enough reputation :)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't encoding the data in a format that PHP can decode and populate `$_POST` with. You are sending a plain text string.

Change:

```
data: target,
```

to

```
data: { target: this.href },
```

Comment: it doesn't work and it's still gave me an error, i have updated my script above and add some information

Answer (score 0):

When sending data via AJAX like you are, you have to replicate a form submission, e.g.

```
$.ajax(...
   data: 'foo'
);
```

will send a bare string 'foo' over to the server. But having

```
$.ajax(...
    data: 'bar=foo'; // key=value pair
    // OR
    data: {bar: 'foo'} // javascript key/value object
);
```

you'll get the proper data for PHP to populate $_GET/$_POST for you. No key/value pair, no entry in $_GET/$_POST. It's that simple.

Comment: it doesn't work and it's still gave me an error, i have updated my script above

Answer (score 0):

Mate in your ajax definition shouldnt you pass the data as array?  try changing the data: line with the below, should work for you:

```
data: { target: the_varibable_you_want_to_pass_by_post }
```

EDIT: as per your comment and edited OP source and @Arthur answer

```
 $(".header_nav li a").click(function(){
     var clicked_link = $(this); //the variable stores the refference to the clicked "a" element
        $.ajax({
        url: 'dynamic.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { target: clicked_link.href }, //so now you can reffer to the href of the "a"
                 success: $.ajax({
                 url: 'dynamic.php',
                 type: 'POST',
                 data: { target: clicked_link.href },
                 dataType: 'html',                
                 success: function(data){
                 $(".container").html(data)
                 }
        })
      })
```

In your previous code, the "this" did not reffer to the clicked link but to the ajax object that does not have the 'href' attribute.

Comment: it doesn't work and it's still gave me an error, i have updated my script above

Comment: same like arthur, and it's gave me same error: Notice: Undefined index: target in xxx.php on line 2
default_target_valueTest ajax

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, that you don't send any data when making the secong request:

```
$(".header_nav li a").click(function(){
  $.ajax({
  url: 'dynamic.php',
  type: 'POST',
  data: { target: this.href }, //i can see the data here
  success: $.ajax({
           url: 'dynamic.php', //notice the same PHP script
           dataType: 'html', // where is the data in this request?               
           success: setTimeout(function(data){
           $(".container").html(data)
           }), 1000)
  })
});
```

So at first it works, but when performing a second request, PHP can't find the 'target' because you are not sending it.

And it's better to cache the href first:

```
$(".header_nav li a").click(function() {
    var href = this.href;
    $.ajax({
        url: 'dynamic.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            target: href //data for first request
        },
        success: $.ajax({
            url: 'dynamic.php',
            dataType: 'html',
            data: {
                target: href //data for the second request
            },        
            success: setTimeout(function(data) {
                $(".container").html(data)
            }),
            1000);
        })
    });
});
```

Or another solution is to check if the "target" exists in PHP:

```
<?php
    $target = isset($_POST['target']) ? $_POST['target'] : 'default_target_value';

    function home(){
        // some data like echo and so on
    }

    switch($target) {
      case "home": home();
          break;
          // and so on
          default;
    }
    echo "Test ajax";
?>
```

Comment: i have updated my php and jquery, and it's gave me same error: Notice: Undefined index: target in xxx.php on line 2
default_target_valueTest ajax

Comment: And what exactly is on line 2? Seems there is some code missing that you don't show to us.

Comment: So in your PHP code, this line `$target = isset($_POST['target']) ? $_POST['target'] : 'default_target_value';` should be at the very top right after `<?php`

Comment: i'm changing my php code, that's because i want to debug it into the container, and the result is above, `$target = $_POST["target"];
  echo $target`, produce undefined index, but the second command produce `default_target_value` string, that's mean my ajax that posting `this.href` and get the result is not work :( is the problem were in my xampp or what?

Comment: it's very annoying, when i'm changing `$target = $_POST["target"];
` into `$target = $_GET["target"];` the echo $target would work and it's give me a response on my container = `xxx.php#blogdefault_target_valueTest ajax` So what's wrong with my **POST** ajax?

Comment: see my solution above! :)

Comment: Check your code, in the first request you have `type: 'POST'`, but in the second you don't have that line! So your first request in `POST` and second one defaults to `GET`